# how to pass cookies from nodejs app to another server using request

Tags: node.js, cookies, request

i need to pass all the cookies from 1 server to another server in  nodejs/express.
i am using request-promise to do HTTP request and cookie parser to parse the cookies on my app.

here is a pseudo code for the desired functionality

```js
router.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
  options = {
      method: "get",
      uri: 'http://example.com',
      cookies: req.cookies // this is the desire functionality
  }
  request(options).then()
});
```

Thanks (:

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should pass your cookies inside header object like this :

```
  router.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
  options = {
      method: "get",
      uri: 'http://example.com',
      headers: {
         Cookie: req.cookies
      }
  }
  request(options).then()
});
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: tried it.  doesn`t work. i know request uses cookie jar but i don`t know he best way to pass the cookies to the jar

Comment: I edited my answer, can you try with "Cookie" instead of "cookies" ?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just parsing the cookies to string with loop

```js
for (let key in req.cookies)
  cookies += key + '=' + req.cookies[key] + ";";

if (cookies !== "") {

    if (options.headers !== undefined && options.headers.Cookie !== undefined) {
        options.headers.Cookie += ';' + cookies.substr(0, cookies.length - 1);
    } else {
        if (options.headers === undefined) {
            options.headers = {};
        }
        options.headers.Cookie = cookies.substr(0, cookies.length - 1);
    }
}
```